# How to export umbraco content

Tags: xml, xslt, umbraco

I'm new and I use Umbraco and asp.net 
My problem is that I need to export a lot of files that are in content (Umbraco). I tried with EyeCatch XML Export, but doesn't work. I tried to create a new package so that I can import in a other Umbraco, but that is not what I need. I need the content file in a XML file and in XSL file. 
For example, I need all files that are under the homepage, with the own image, etc.
Does anyone know if there is some free package, or does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at UmbracoAPIController's. They will allow you to easily expose any of your data type's property values as XML or JSON. It is essentially an extension of Microsoft's Web API and is very easy to create. All you do is create a POCO class to store your content in, whose name ends in "Controller". You then extend UmbracoApiController. For example:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Core.Models;
using Umbraco.Web;
using Umbraco.Web.WebApi;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyDocTypePoco
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    }


    public class MyDocTypeController : UmbracoApiController
    {
        [UmbracoAuthorize, AcceptVerbs("GET, POST"), System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public MyDocTypePoco GetPage(int id)
        {
            IPublishedContent node = Umbraco.TypedContent(id); // get our CMS node

            var myPoco = new MyDocTypePoco // instantiate POCO and populate
            {
                Name = node.GetPropertyValue<string>(node.Name), //  property of IPublishedContent
                ImageUrl = node.GetPropertyValue<string>("imageUrl") // my document type's custom property's alias
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this would assume your image file was stored in a property with an alias of "imageUrl".

Once you've compiled your code, you should be able to call your service using this URL.

```
http://localhost/umbraco/api/MyDocType/GetPage?id=1234
```

1234 is the ID of the content node, and replace localhost with your domain you are running your site under (and add the port, etc). Note that you can remove the "UmbracoAuthorize" statement to allow you to view you service without having to be authenticated and logged in to the backend of Umbraco. This should never be done on live sites unless you are sure the data exposed by your controller is harmless.

Have a look [here](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/WebApi/) for more reading. Welcome aboard the Umbraco train! It's great fun and we're going from strength to strength in terms of what we can achieve.

Comment: Also - if you are not bothered about the format of the XML you want, take a look at the Umbraco.config file in the App_Data folder. It contains a view of all content in the Umbraco content tree. I have written code before now which will parse that into another system. When someone updates a node in the Content tree, the file will be updated.

Comment: Thaaaaaaank you very much :D I found what I need, but I didn't use POCO :) Thank you

Comment: So glad I could help. I hope you enjoy Umbraco as much as all of the rest of us do!

Answer (score 1):

There is already an XML file containing all the contents of your website, at /app_data/umbraco.config (Its extension of .config is what throws you off the scent).

Internally Umbraco uses this XML file when rendering all content.

Comment: Yes, but there are all the files. I need just there that are under the homepage, there are like 30 pages, and I need all that in one export xml.